# Fluent NHibernate mapping IList<Point> as value to single column

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have this class:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Point> Vectors { get; set; }
}
```

How can I map the `Vectors` in Fluent NHibernate to a single column (as value)? I was thinking of this:

```
public class Vectors : ISerializable
{
    public IList<Point> Vectors { get; set; }

    /* Here goes ISerializable implementation */
}

public class MyEntity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Vectors Vectors { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to map the `Vectors` like this, hoping that Fluent NHibernate will initialize `Vectors` class as standard ISerializable?

Or how else could I map `IList<Point>` to a single column? I guess I will have to write the serialization/deserialization routines myself, which is not a problem, I just need to tell FNH to use those routines.

I guess I should use `IUserType` or `ICompositeUserType`, but I have no idea how to implement them, and how to tell FNH to cooperate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found an answer. :-)

Heading `UserTypeConvention<T>` at:
http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Available_conventions
for custom type conversions.

This is for implementing custom type convertors:
http://intellect.dk/post/Implementing-custom-types-in-nHibernate.aspx

Additional related links I've found:
http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/rhouston/archive/2008/03/23/mapping-strings-to-booleans-using-nhibernate-s-iusertype.aspx
http://www.martinwilley.com/net/code/nhibernate/usertype.html
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210127201844/http://geekswithblogs.net/opiesblog/archive/2006/08/13/87880.aspx)
http://kozmic.pl/archive/2009/10/12/mapping-different-types-with-nhibernate-iusertype.aspx
[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20100516024604/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/howard_dierking/archive/2007/04/23/nhibernate-custom-mapping-types.aspx)

`UserTypeConvention<T>` usage:
http://jagregory.com/writings/fluent-nhibernate-auto-mapping-type-conventions/

The most important code in last link is this:

```
public class ReplenishmentDayTypeConvention : ITypeConvention
{
  public bool CanHandle(Type type)
  {
    return type == typeof(ReplenishmentDay);
  }

  public void AlterMap(IProperty propertyMapping)
  {
    propertyMapping
      .CustomTypeIs<ReplenishmentDayUserType>()
      .TheColumnNameIs("RepOn");
  }
}
```

Where `ReplenishmentDayUserType` is `IUserType`-derived class and `ReplenishmentDay` is the class, which should be converted using your user type converter.

And this:

```
autoMappings
  .WithConvention(convention =>
  {
    convention.AddTypeConvention(new ReplenishmentDayTypeConvention());
    // other conventions
  });
```

Comment: +1 - Also, could you edit your answer with the code for your solution? I've been looking for a nice, simple example using UserTypeConvention...

Comment: Well I don't have my code, since I didn't had time for this lately, but I will update the answer with some additional info I've found.

Comment: Edited. If you are going to try the code, please let me know if there are any problems, as I'm interested if it works.